# How is My Wi-Fi configured for port-forwarding?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I wants to tweak at some of my network for learning purposes. But I don't know exactly how my Wi-Fi is configured. The ISP installs an indoor-CPE to my house and I am connecting to it with my Wi-Fi Adapter. When I hit the address Wi-Fi is connecting (192.168.99.1), only the following information is available:

[image: CPE info]

So my question is how can I tweak this set-up to allow config like port forwarding? and how the outside from the WLAN can reach to this CPE or can they just connect to My IP? I search at google for port-forwarding but almost all tutorials and explaination are with third-party routers and none of them are like this.

P.S I am pretty new on networking so please bear with me if I questioning wrong.

Comment: With a LAN address of 10.x.x.x you're unlikely to be able to do any user config at all on your exterior ports. Chances are you're on [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) which doesn't expose you from the 'outside world' at all.

Comment: "doesn't exponse me from outside word" mean every connection I made are went to the ISP internal line/server and they handle those request and response to me back? I will look more into in the CGNAT.

Comment: but isn't that how ISP normally works. Can you please explain the"doesn't expose" part more.

Comment: short answer is call your ISP and ask them how to access management on the device. you can ask them if they support port forwarding at that time. Personally I've never been on a CGNAT based ISP, but my modem has a 10.x.y.z address. I'm just several hops away from the gateways where my public IP is assigned. Not saying you are or aren't on CGNAT, just that you might as well ask them.

Comment: easy to determine if you are on CGNAT. google whatsmyip - if the address is `100.64.0.0` - `100.127.255.255` then you are on CGNAT and no amount of tweaks will allow port forwarding

Comment: @JaromandaX That is not how it all works. ISP's can use any private address nets they wish including 100.64.0.0/10. However, those addresses should never be seen in the internet, since the end point will have no way of routing them back. That is the point of CGNAT, they are translated to public IP addresses.

Comment: my address is regular 2**.**.***.*** and thanks all for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how the outside from the WLAN can reach to this CPE

Most likely they cannot, as it hasn't even been issued a public IP address. The "Data IP" is from the private-use 10.0.0.0/8 range; this usually indicates CGNAT.

The CPE appears to be highly custom (likely made for the ISP specifically), and it's possible that they *didn't add* the "port forwarding" functionality as they knew they would no longer be directly issuing public IPv4 addresses to customers anyway (in which case such functions would be useless) or that they just haven't added the feature *yet* and it might appear sometime in the future after a firmware upgrade.

> but isn't that how ISP normally works. Can you please explain the"doesn't expose" part more.

No, it's not. Normally the ISP would directly issue at least your CPE a public IP address that other Internet hosts could directly send packets to.

Comment: After I asked this question, I learned that ISP provided fiber optic cable to us and it is routed to their CPE through ethernet. so, If I bought and routed it to commercial router with port forwarding functionality, can port forwarding be done or issuing public ip address  would be remained?